# I am trying to automate Flipkart where while trying to click on submenu of the header menu it is getting detaching from the DOM, how to handle this?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

The submenus are getting appeared in the DOM only when we hover over the main menu.
So after hovering over main menu using Actions class the submenus are coming, but then again when I am trying to get into the submenu it is getting detached from the DOM.
Please help me on this.

```
public void goToMenTopWearSectionFromFashion() throws InterruptedException
    {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        try {
        act.moveToElement(FashionHeaderLink).perform();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='_1psGvi SLyWEo']//div[text()='Fashion']"))).perform();
        }
        try {
            if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3XS_gI _7qr1OC']//a[1]")).isDisplayed())
            {
                System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3XS_gI _7qr1OC']//a[1]")).isDisplayed());
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='_3XS_gI _7qr1OC']//a[1]")).click();
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}  
    }
```

Comment: Share the error stacktrace, relevant info or page url. those xpath looks absolute, try to use relative xpath.

Comment: wondering if instead of trying to click on it you get the href value of the link and navigate there directly. Also,  maybe easier to locate it by (partial?) link text "Men's Top Wear"

Comment: Here is how I made it work in Python. 1) make the waits explicit. 2) After the hover, wait for the Men's Top Wear link to be clickable, but make no attempt to click it 3)chained a call to get the href attribute and stored that in a variable 4) navigated to that saved href 5) I was able to locate By (full) link text on "Fashion" and "Men's Top Wear"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hover, trying to move to click on Men's Top Wear was sometimes causing it to disappear along the way. I experienced the same by hand if I moved diagonally rather than straight down. Instead,in your 2nd try block you can do the following:

```
if(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Men's Top Wear")).isDisplayed())
        {
            String urlSave = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Men's Top Wear")).getAttribute("href");
            driver.get(urlSave);
        }
```

Probably it would work with your locator, too.

Comment: by the way,         act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.linkText("Fashion"))).perform();
works, too.

Comment: Jeremy- Many thanks for looking into this and giving me a good solution, let me try and get back to you with the outcome.